# How to run php on a button click

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have been browsing trough a lot of threads, and the only suitable solution for my situation I found was this:

PHP:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
        my php code goes here
  
}
        ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="usp-form-23" class="usp-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" data-validate="parsley" data-persist="garlic" novalidate>
     

<input name="usp-title" type="text" value="" data-required="true" required="required" maxlength="99999" placeholder="Answer" class="usp-input usp-input-title" />

<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="usp-submit usp-submit-default" value="Send Message" />


</form>
```

But it doesn't work.

Maybe I'm missing something?

Need help.

P.S. I can't use an external php file. Only php code inside the same file, because of the variables I need to grab from the post.

I also can't use $_GET, because if a person refreshes the page, my php will be repeated, which I don't want. I only need to run my php once.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by *doesn't work*, when you click the submit, is there anything happen? 2) you can use an external php file, just specify the `action` attribute for the form, you can get `$_POST` value on your external file.

Comment: I mean, my form is sent as usual, but the php code didn't execute.

Comment: You might want to do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see the content of your post request, you might have javascript interferes the form submission

Comment: `<form id="usp-form-23" class="usp-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" data-validate="parsley" data-persist="garlic" novalidate>` The action is empty, no php path there

Comment: correct. It's empty, but the form gets submitted to the current page. It's empty by default on User Submitted Posts plugin.

Comment: I did `<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>` it outputed: `array(0) { }`. So that means $_POST is empty? I don't understand.

Comment: Do you have HTML and PHP code in the same file? Where is the submitted form data supposed to be going, to which PHP file?